# JSP Function Run Error

Tags: jsp

I have written the following jsp code in a jsp page for testing

```
<%!
    public String sayHello(String myName)
    {
          out.println("Hello Java"); // this line shows error
          return "Hello"+myName;
    }
%>

<%
  String str="William";
%>

   <%=sayHello(str)%>
```

If i remove the following line the page runs without error

```
         out.println("Hello Java");
```

Again, if i run a jsp file with only the following line included (not above codes) then also it runs well

```
         out.println("Hello Java");
```

Please help me where am i doing mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `JSP` implicit *objects* in methods. In order to access implicit object in custom methods, you have pass the reference of *implicit* (`JspWriter`) object to the method but use of Java code in JSP is *highly discouraged*.

Fore more information read [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) and [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Comment: Thanks AVD. But please tell me how to pass reference of implicit (JspWrite)